# Determining Z1 for voltage divider of RF Matching Circuit

Tags: rf, transfer-function, impedance-matching, frequency-response

I have a problem where I was given an RF circuit with a series RL load. I am tasked in finding a matching L circuit and determining the values of the components. I used a smith chart to determine that a shunt capacitor and series inductor is a suitable L network topology and determined their values.

The second part of the problem was to find the frequency response of the voltage across the load resistor. It comes down to two voltage dividers to derive the transfer function. I calculated the first voltage divider for the voltage at the shunt capacitor, straight forward. I then used a second application of a voltage divider to get Vout. My problem is I don't know what Z1 should be the second voltage divider, and I am asking for help on that.

[image: Initial Problem]
[image: My Matching Network]
[image: My Current work and where I am stuck (in blue)]